# Hourly updated view in Django/postgresql

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-celery, sql-view

I am looking to populate a page with active items in Django.

```
item_active = DateTimeRangeField()
```

Any smarter way to compare the current time: Theoretical "views.py":

```
def time_now():
    return timezone.now()

def index(request):
    item_list = item.objects.raw('''SELECT col1, col2 FROM item_table
    WHERE upper(item_active) >= %s AND lower(item_active) <= %s''', [time_now])
```

An efficient implementation of the time comparison would be helpful, but my intuition tells me that a SQL-view updated hourly (using Django and Celery or postgreSQL updated hourly and on_table_update) only containing active objects is the smartest.

So for the preferred way, how do I implement the materialized view through Django/Celery or the Datebase side? (Hourly and on_table_update)

Answer (score 0):

Working with range fields in Django isn't very well documented, IMO.

If you're just looking for Items where the current moment (timezone.now()) overlaps with the item_active field's range, this should do the trick:

```
def index(request):
    item_list = Item.objects.filter(item_active__contains=timezone.now())
```

---

Edit: Make sure you're using standard Django naming conventions to make it easier for others to help you. Classes should always be caps.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/